# How do I use groupby without making other values in the column NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get the lowest value from the column "Assignment Start Date", based on the "Employee no" and the "Client Group Name" into the column named "start".

I want the "start" column to be filled with the minimum "Assignment Start Date" for every "Client Group Name" and every "Employee no".

So far, I have written the below code:

```
for i, j in test_n.iterrows():
l = test_n.iloc[i]['Employee no']
test_n['start'] = test_n['Assignment Start Date'].where(test_n['Employee no'] == l).groupby(test_n['Client Group Name_y']).transform('min')
```

This code works fine, and generates the desired result. But it over-writes the previous entries with NaN values. It is only working for the last 'Employee no'. I want it to work for all 'Employee no' without making other columns NaN.
How do I stop it from doing that so that I get minimum values for all rows ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line of code regarding `test_n`

```
dfc = test_n.groupby(['Employee no','Client Group Name_y'])['Assignment Start Date']
test_n = test_n.assign(start=dfc.transform(min))
test_n
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to iterate over every row in the data frame and replace the values one at a time. This is not very efficient and can introduce errors. An alternative method would be to use the
[Groupby Method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). The group by creates groups in the given columns then you can apply other methods to each group.

To use this you would first construct the groups you want to understand the data by and select the data you want to find the min.

`test_n_groups = test_n.groupby(by=['Employee no','Client Group Name_y'])['Assignment Start Date']`

You would then use a few methods together to add the minimum as a new column to your original data frame.

First you would apply the transform method to the grouped data to get an column that has the min start date for each row

`min_group = test_n_groups.transform(min)`

Then you would apply the assign method to the original data frame using your groups with the name start and the transform for the minimum from your group

`test_n.assign(start=min_group)`

Last I would print out the data frame to see what it looks like

`test_n.head(15)`